# overlapping issues SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

**Every expression is left align, I don't know why some labels are overlap and have more space.
see pic 2, label cancer within 5 years is overlap with expression.
see pic 3, output for unresponsive state has more space than output 1**

**How do I fix those problems?**

[image: SSRS Report]

[image: OUTPUT 1]

[image: OUTPUT2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely to me that SSRS is adjusting the size of some surrounding object and that is causing these fields to get bumped. I would check into the surrounding objects and make sure that their CanGrow and CanShrink Attributes are set to false. I would also recommend putting the expression in the same text box as the description (i.e., copying and pasting the expression into the "Cancer within 5 years: " textbox.